# Emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_29 was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have tried every method and followed it given on Stack overflow but still i get this error and even i have updated all requirements.

Comment: There can be many reasons for this issue as it's a generic message. I recommend you to try and run your emulator from CLI so that you can have more description of the error. See this: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: i followed the link but i'm getting this error 
emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168) (CL:N/A)
Warning: Quick Boot /  not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

Answer (score 0):

i tried alot of the things on stack overflow but what worked for me was going to `Turn Windows features on or off` and uncheck **`Virtual Machine Platform`**.

Refresh laptop and try running the emulator again, make sure `HAXM` is installed too though.